# Split and add Text EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel, split

I would like to split some text and then add `"_@"` to the split text

Eg.

```
S106-137-800_BOMS_0.xls >          S106-137-800_BOMS_@           0
```

here is my code so far :

```
    k = InStr(str, "_")
    j = InStr(k + 1, str, "_")
    i = InStr(j + 1, str, ".")

    rw.Offset(0, 1) = Left(str, j - 1)
    rw.Offset(0, 2) = Mid(str, j + 1, i - j - 1)
```

Is there a way to split and Add `"_@` as shown in the e.g ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear because this is only half the code we see. Do you mean something like `rw.Offset(0, 1) = Left(str, j - 1) & "_@"`? You can also have a look at the [Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx). Always add to your questions: What your code actually does (example of your actual result) and what you expect as result.

Comment: @Peh Sorry, i though that code would be sufficient, but yes that is what i was looking for Thanks! Please write that in an answer so i can register it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `InStrRev` Function to get the position (from the right) of the first `_` from the end:

```
i = InStrRev(Str, "_")

rw.Offset(, 1).Value = Left(Str, i) & "@"
rw.Offset(, 2).Value = Mid(Str, i + 1, InStr(Str, ".") - i - 1)
```

Comment: This time you won ;)

Comment: @Peh I'm not against yu, right ? with you helping new guys stepping into VBA, and also learning new stuff

Comment: Of course I'm totally fine! You got my vote for suggesting `InStrRev`. Always good to see different solutions.

Comment: @Peh I remember using it because I saw it here on another post a while ago